# In Android How can I specify which activity should handle my intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 applications `A and B.`

I want to start an activity in `B` from `A`. So I am using an **implicit intent**. Is there any way to make sure that only the activity in `B` is invoked by the intent?

i.e In the event that a hacker puts his application on the device trying to receive the same intent, I want to prevent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the setPackage method to specify whicj app should handle the intent. Here is an example using ZXing:

```
final String ZXING = "com.google.zxing.client.android";
Intent intent = new Intent(ZXING + ".SCAN");
intent.setPackage(ZXING);
```

Comment: @Krishna:what about when an hacker get your package name and fire same intent as give in above answer???

Comment: So what? It still goes to your app.

Comment: @Philip Sheard: security hole for hacker still remains. i'm ok with with your solution in Activity A not in Activity B ...

Comment: You mean that some activity C can also launch the same intent? That is true, but it was not part of the original question. Your solution answers another question that was never asked in the first place. You should not mark someone down because you lose an argument. That is not only petty and mean spirited, but it is also an abuse of this forum, and brings it into disrepute. You should be ashamed of yourself.

Comment: Hi Imran, I am fine with someone else invoking my activity. The worst that can happen is I will just get a password from user, verify it and return a OK or CANCEL to the caller. I don't pass any sensitive info back to the caller.

Comment: @PhilipSheard: i'm sorry if i hurt you.

Comment: You did not hurt me, but you did hurt yourself.

Comment: @PhilipSheard: Is your solution is an example of explicit intent?? Please let me know.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

as [documention](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported) says about `android:exported=false`:

`android:exported`
Whether or not the activity can be launched by components of other applications — "true" if it can be, and "false" if not. If "false", the activity can be launched only by components of the same application or applications with the same user ID.
The default value depends on whether the activity contains intent filters. The absence of any filters means that the activity can be invoked only by specifying its exact class name. This implies that the activity is intended only for application-internal use (since others would not know the class name). So in this case, the default value is "false". On the other hand, the presence of at least one filter implies that the activity is intended for external use, so the default value is "true".
This attribute is not the only way to limit an activity's exposure to other applications. You can also use a permission to limit the external entities that can invoke the activity (see the permission attribute).

so ,use `android:exported=false` in Activity B and use `IntentSender` in Activty for getting infromation of Intent means from which component want to start your Activty B

Answer (score 0):

If you are using explicit intent, activity specified in intent would be invoked only.

You can add Data, Action, Categories, to limit filtering of component to target only your activity, in case of implicit intent.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I am using implicit intent. Corrected the question.

Comment: I agree. But aren't all those something that can be emulated by a hacker? Can't he also specify all those in his manifest and still catch the same intent?

Comment: I agree to your doubts, but it is how implicit intents works, If you are using more specific fields in IntentFilter then no use of ImplicitIntents coz, it is better in that case to invoke explicit intents

Comment: But I can't use an explicit intent since the activity is in another application right?

Comment: you can use explicit intent even if your activity is in another application, set exported flag of activity in manifest to true, and you can use that activity in any application

Answer (score 0):

You could encrypt any data sent in the intent using a simple Public/Private key encryption.  A common approach is to use PGP encryption and Im sure there is a library that is compatible with Android out there.

This would make sure that any hacker would not be able to steal the data sent via intents, as long as they don't have the private key.

That being said, it may be tricky to handle the private key as a good hacker may be able to de-obfuscate/de-compile your application and grab your key.  Therefore you may need to keep said key on a central server.

Comment: My requirement is not to restrict who can invoke my activity. It is the opposite. I am fine with anyone invoking the activity in B. But I want to make sure that when A sends the intent, none other than B is able to catch it.

Comment: Ok. Here my requirement is slightly different. I am not passing any data between the two. A sends the intent to B, upon which B takes a password from the user and after verifying the password returns OK or CANCEL to A. So I don't want someone to just write an app which takes the intent and always return OK. Also I don't want to put the password checking logic in A, because I have 6 or 7 apps like A which all depend on the same password.

Comment: I guess using startActivityForResult as andranikAzizbekyan suggested would work then.