# Android Intent setPackage for 2 or more specific app

Tags: android, share

From this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9596062/837059), I can set the Intent to a specific app by setPackage.
For my scenario I need to share text to either WhatsApp, Instagram or Line. Is it possible to set more than one package bundle ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't possible. What you can do is to call `setPackage(String)` for one of them, send it and then rinse and repeat.

You may want to use PackageManager to see if the apps are installed, but from a security view point setPackage is not secure, because any app can use WhatsApp, Instagram,.. packages if they're not already installed. Assuming the intent is for a broadcast, maybe you should consider using an implicit intent as other apps may be interested?